# Is it possible to make \copy insert files that have less columns than the created table?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-copy

I'm using the following `psql` command to import data to the postgresql database:

```
\COPY tablename FROM '/home/user/mycsv.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';'  NULL AS 'null';
```

This command works fine for csv files that have the same number of columns that `tablename`. However, I'm on a project where there are old csv files with less columns than the new files and I need to insert these old files inside postgresql. Is there any way of making the `\copy` command to insert the missing data as `null` on the extra columns instead of returning the following error?

```
 ERROR:  missing data for column "firstMissingColumn"
```

Right now, the only possible solution that I see would be modifying the old csv files by filling the extra columns with `null`. But I don't see that as an ideal solution. Is there any easier way of solving this problem? Can I insert files with less columns than the created table using `\copy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list target columns. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> For `COPY FROM`, each field in the file is inserted, in order, into the specified column. Table columns not specified in the `COPY FROM` column list will receive their default values.

Unless you have set custom column defaults, the default is `null` like you desire. So:

```
\COPY tablename(col1, col2, col3) FROM '/home/user/mycsv.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' NULL AS 'null';
```